# How to solve the problem: java.io.FileNotFoundException when deploying jee app to Wildfly 25

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly

I get the error below when deploying the app to Wildfly:

> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit."funmusic-back.war#productPU"" => "jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: productPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: productPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to open specified script target file for writing : productDrop.ddl
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: productDrop.ddl (Permission denied)"}}

The tricky point I met is, when I start the wildfly by standalone.sh, it is alright. However, when I start it using systemctl start wildfly, this problem happen. I am wondering whether it is the problem related to the Domain Mode and Standalone Mode of Wildfly, but could not recognize the missing piece I should learn in order to solve the problem. My OS using is CentOS 7 and the Wildfly version is 25.

Below is the persistence.xml for your reference:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
         version="2.2">
<!-- transaction-type is the type of transactions used by EntityManagers from this persistence unit. -->
<persistence-unit name="productPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <properties>
        <property name ="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"></property>
        <property name ="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"></property>
        <property name ="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="productCreate.ddl"></property>
        <property name ="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="productDrop.ddl"></property>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I get a single @Entity which is a very simple POJO with a few fields within. As it is simple, I am going to skip it here.

It would be grateful if you could point out the cause of the problem and give me some insight of it. Also, document reference with section specified would be more appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess that when you are starting manually you are using a different user, hence *Permission denied*

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are right, I am using a different user whether than the user added according to the guide I find in: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wildfly-on-centos-7/   . However, I still do not know how to start it manually by different user...Thank you very much :)

Comment: have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/841099/systemd-grant-an-unprivileged-user-permission-to-alter-one-specific-service